# Lazy strategy on OpenCL1.1

Tags: opencl

Is there any lazy strategy in OpenCL1.1 to handle data transfer? I know that CUDA has this strategy so you can allocate more memory than what you have on device.

Comment: Can you give a usage example? I cannot imagine why one would do that.

Comment: For example you have list of structures linked in host mem but not in order because during the computations it has been updated. Then you are supposed to send part of the list for more computations to GPU but the needed information may already uploaded or not. So later you can decide to fetch more of the list. Lazy strategy gives you this chance to upload data as they are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not as familiar with OpenCL, but found a related [NVIDIA forum discussion](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=199804).

Also thought I'd reply on the mention of CUDA in case anyone comes across later...

I don't think there's a way in native CUDA to allocate more memory than physically available on the device.  In fact, even on larger cards, you can't allocate one large contiguous array because the card has separate memory banks, e.g. back in the C1060 days I recall hitting a limit of something around 1.5gb on 3gb cards.  Could you provide some details on what you mean by CUDA allowing such large allocations?

If you're using [ArrayFire](http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire) (or [Jacket](http://accelereyes.com/jacket)), they have the basic idea of [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory): if you have lots of little allocations that total more than available on the card, then it only keeps the most important out on the device while other pieces are kept back on host until needed.